# How to use multiple common properties in a bean with a Spring config file?

Tags: java, spring

I need to set the properties on a bean with common fields from different "places" so something along the lines of:

```
<bean id="parent1" abstract="true">
    <property name="commonField" value="parent1_val"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="parent2" abstract="true">
    <property name="commonField2" value="parent2_val"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="injectDemo1" class="spring.testClasses.InjectDemo1" parent="parent1" parent="parent2>
    <property name="val1" value="val1"/>
</bean>
```

The above example does not work because only one parent attribute is allowed. But this is what I need to do; is there a mechanism in Spring that will allow me to set properties from multiple sources. 
I looked at property files to do the same thing but properties files cannot hold Sets, Lists or Maps which I need or can they?

Something like:

```
<bean id="injectDemo1" class="spring.testClasses.InjectDemo1">
   <property name="val1" value="val1"/>
   <property name="commonField1" value="${prop1}"/>
   <property name="commonField2" value="${prop2}"/>
</bean>
```

I hope I've explained it okay?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Spring beans support multiple inheritance, for the same reason the makers of Java decided to not support muliple inheritance.